# SSH won't work in new version of OS X 10.8.4

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop

I was using a previous version of OS X and used to connected to a server with an SSH console. It used to run X11 after loading my requested programs (Mathematica) on the remote server and was working properly.

Recently I upgraded my Mac to the latest version (OS X 10.8.4) and SSH is now not loading the "X" anymore. I therefore access my requested programs from the remote server.

How can I fix the problem? I downloaded an extra version of X11 and installed it, but there were connection failures in the graphical interface. It was working with properly with X11 in the previous version.

[image]

Comment: What version of OS X did you run before? What exactly are you doing when you connect to the remote server? Which programs do you open and what commands do you enter?

Comment: → slhck: the one integrated with OS X 10.7.
→ Alex: which X11 version did you install? Where did you install it?
Could you add in your original question the typical output of:
`type xterm`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos the latest version XQuartz

Comment: @slhck it was 10.5 something .It was 2010 product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to install [XQuarts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) as mentioned by oozic.

Troubleshoot the connection by logging in with verbosity.

```
ssh -xvvv foo@bar
```

Verify that you have the DISPLAY environment variable [configured](http://dyhr.com/2009/09/05/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) in your mac. Here is what mine looks like.

```
env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-51CsPO/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Comment: You are awesome!!!Thanks.The problem has been solved.Please tell me what I have to read to know useful commands in terminal of the mac?

Comment: @Alex Glad to hear, I'd suggest studying the LPI linux certification courses if you would like to learn more about Unix/Linux/Mac.  http://www.lpi.org

Comment: Thanks for the offer but not that professional. I want to have basic knowledge with kind of learning myself.A book??Or internet links?

Comment: Here is a wikibook http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LPI_Linux_Certification/Configure_Fundamental_BIOS_Settings and here is another book http://product.half.ebay.com/Running-Linux-by-Matt-Welsh-and-Matthias-Kalle-Dalheimer-2005-Paperback-Revised/49214492&tg=info This might be a good question to ask on superuser (Where can I learn about unix?)

Comment: many thanks for the help. I might ask the question later.That is great and enough for me now.

Answer (score 3):

They removed x11 support in OSX since Lion 10.7.x
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293

They suggest you to use this:
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

I used once and it was working fine (connecting to lxde remote desktop)

Comment: I have XQuarts on it.It wont work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to reinstall the latest version of GSI-SSHTerm.

Ensure also that your client accepts the server's certificate,
especially if the server is using a self-signed certificate.
You may need to update your CA certificates files.