# Fedora Server: X11 won't forward over SSH?

Tags: ssh, fedora, xorg

My roommate and I just set up a fedora install on a computer and trying to set it up with some server application as well. However, we can't get X11 to forward, with a number of random errors:

```
$ fluxbox
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
```

and a bunch of other hoop-la like that, followed by:

```
BScreen::BScreen: an error occured while querying the X server.
    another window manager already running on displaylocalhost:10.0
Error: Couldn't find screens to manage.
Make sure you don't have another window manager running.
```

Or if we try to start a gnome-session:

```
$ gnome-session
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

** (process:3643): WARNING **: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

And a window pops up in Xquartz (I have a mac) that says:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system
>   can't recover.

And it tries me to log out, which does nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have xquarts installed and then export your DISPLAY environment variable on your Mac.

```
env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-51CsPO/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

[SSH won't work in new version of OS X 10.8.4](https://superuser.com/questions/629836/ssh-wont-work-in-new-version-of-os-x-10-8-4/633544#633544)

Comment: I get the following error:

BScreen::BScreen: an error occured while querying the X server.
 another window manager already running on displaylocalhost:11.0
Error: Couldn't find screens to manage.
Make sure you don't have another window manager running.

Comment: @mttalxndrgrrtt That can happen if you ssh in then run `startx`. http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?149154-starting-fluxbox-with-x11-forwarding Add the exact commands you are running to the question. You should be doing something like: `ssh -vvvX foo && xeyes`